# Current working method to install zipline? tried everything

Tags: python, python-3.5, python-3.7, zipline

Hey im trying to install zipline on Python but nothing works

I already tried it with Python 3.7 but it fails at the following libaries bcolz
lru dict
bottleneck
cyordereddict
(and zipline itself)

I tried it with Python 3.5 as recommended in this guide (https://pythonprogramming.net/zipline-local-install-python-programming-for-finance/)
same results.
I tried it creating an anaconda environment with pyhton 3.5 ... again same results.

the only thing that "worked was installing it without dependencies, but then i would have to install trading-calendars and some other libaries (which also didnt work to install):

pip install --no-deps zipline-1.3.0-cp37-cp37m-win_amd64.whl

Could somebody tell me a current working method on installing zipline?

Answer (score 11):

zipline is as of now, not compatible with python version > 3.5 and is very specific to versions of dependent packages. Most of these packages has new versions.
https://github.com/quantopian/zipline/issues/2514

Best method would be to install with conda.
Once you had installed Anaconda/Miniconda you need to downgrade it to 4.6.11, below commands may help.

1. conda config --set allow_conda_downgrades true
2. conda install conda=4.6.11
3. conda create -n env_zipline python=3.5
4. activate env_zipline
5. conda install -c Quantopian zipline

Comment: One of the even more limiting issues is that zipline is bound to pandas 0.22, which is pretty old. It currently seems also not possible to use pyfolio and quantstats in the same environment together with zipline.

Answer (score 0):

To install zipline simply run in your new virtual env:

```
pip install -e git://github.com/shlomikushchi/zipline-trader.git#egg=zipline-trader
```

For more info:

- [Check Docs](https://zipline-trader.readthedocs.io/en/latest/notebooks/Alphalens.html)
- [Edit on GitHub](https://github.com/shlomikushchi/zipline-trader)
- [Lear from video tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=cTLSCjPFQvY)
- [Read blog - Linear Regression For a Momentum Based Trading Strategy Using Zipline Trader](https://alpaca.markets/learn/linear-regression-zipline-trader/)
- [Chat on Slack](https://zipline-live.slack.com/join/shared_invite/zt-2eswh6cg-RkkAfook7cvREnQfit6qGA#/)